# Data not binding (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-binding, binding, uwp

I writing app for UWP (Win 10)

I send data to back-end, get response via json and then write it to file like this

```
searchButton.Click += async  delegate
        {
            telephone = searchtext.Text;

            using (var client = new HttpClient()) // Получение данных со строки поиска и запись в переменную
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"phone", telephone}
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://api.simplegames.com.ua/post/findCastomerPhone.php", content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (responseString != null)
                {
                    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                    Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("result.txt");
                    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, responseString.ToString());
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Клиент найден");
                    dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Посмотреть информацию") { Id = 0 });
                    dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Закрыть") { Id = 1 });
                    dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
                    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
                    if ((int) result.Id == 0)
                    {
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(ResultOfSearch));
                    }
                    }
                else
                {
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Клиента не существует");
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                }
                //Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
            }

        };
```

After this in  ResultOfSearchViewModel.cs file I read data from file and write it to `List` like this.

```
private List<RootObject> ordersList;
    public List<RootObject> OrdersList
    {
        get { return ordersList; }
        set
        {
            ordersList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private RootObject ordersChange;
    public RootObject OrdersChange
    {
        get { return ordersChange; }
        set
        {
            ordersChange = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ResultOfSearchViewModel()
    {
        AllOrders_down();
    }
    public async void AllOrders_down()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
            await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("result.txt");
        string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(text);
        OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);
    }
```

I set breakpoints and see that data downloads, writes to file and after that in List.

But on UI I don't see data.

Here is my xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="OrderList"  ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding OrdersChange, Mode=TwoWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="MyClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="GridInf"  RightTapped="Grid_RightTapped"   Height="155" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                    <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,106,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,56,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And I bind it via `DataContext`, here is code

```
 public sealed partial class ResultOfSearch : Page
{
    public ResultOfSearch()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ResultOfSearchViewModel();
        DetailsList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

Where is my trouble?

Comment: Maybe changing from List to ObservableCollection<> could help you.

Comment: This is strange, because I have code like this in another class and it works, but there I download to variable directly from url @GMazzacua

Comment: basing on the code you provided we can only guess

Comment: In C# and Visual Basic, the generic ObservableCollection<T> class is a good collection choice for data binding, because it implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces. These interfaces provide change notification to bindings when items are added or removed or a property of the list itself changes. If you want your bound controls to update with changes to properties of objects in the collection, the business object should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged. For more info, see Data binding in depth.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code for binding, which I have tested on my side. Please check that data is sure not in the UI since you set the foreground to white. And please ensure you can `OrdersList` has values when debug.